# Block / Disable Windows key and PrtSc key in Excel VBA 7.1 (Tried RegisterHotKey)

Tags: excel, vba, windows, printscreen, registerhotkey

I'm trying to find a way to block Windows key and PrintScreen key in my Excel file (VBA 7.1). Since Application.OnKey method can't be used, my online research points to two solutions: 1) RegisterHotKeys, 2) Keyboard Hook. I've tried RegisterHotKeys since this seems to be the preferred method based on my online research. Pls let me know if there are any other solutions I should explore. I'd also like to share my code below on RegisterHotKeys for both keys that I'm trying to block (in this example, minimizing the window) - when I run it, my excel file hangs and I'm unsure where the error lies.

This is for the Windows key:

```
Const MOD_WIN = &H8
Const PM_REMOVE = &H1
Const WM_HOTKEY = &H312

Type POINTAPI
x As Long
y As Long
End Type

Type MSG
    hwnd As LongPtr
    Message As Long
    wParam As LongPtr
    lParam As LongPtr
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal id As Long, ByVal fsModifiers As Long, ByVal vk As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal id As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PeekMessageA" (lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Public bCancel As Boolean
Sub ProcessMessages()
    Dim Message As MSG
    Do While Not bCancel
    WaitMessage
    If PeekMessage(Message, Application.hwnd, WM_HOTKEY, WM_HOTKEY, PM_REMOVE) Then
        WindowState = vbMinimized
    End If
    DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

Sub SetHotKey()
    Dim ret As Long
    bCancel = False
    ret = RegisterHotKey(Application.hwnd, &HBFFF&, MOD_WIN, 0)
    ProcessMessages
End Sub

Sub UnsetHotKey()
    bCancel = True
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Application.hwnd, &HBFFF&)
End Sub
```

This is for the PrintScreen key:

```
Const PM_REMOVE = &H1
Const WM_HOTKEY = &H312
Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C

Type POINTAPI
x As Long
y As Long
End Type

Type MSG
    hwnd As LongPtr
    Message As Long
    wParam As LongPtr
    lParam As LongPtr
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type

Declare PtrSafe Function RegisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal id As Long, ByVal fsModifiers As Long, ByVal vk As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function UnregisterHotKey Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal id As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PeekMessageA" (lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long
Declare PtrSafe Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Public bCancel As Boolean
Sub ProcessMessages()
    Dim Message As MSG
    Do While Not bCancel
    WaitMessage
    If PeekMessage(Message, Application.hwnd, WM_HOTKEY, WM_HOTKEY, PM_REMOVE) Then
        WindowState = vbMinimized
    End If
    DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub

Sub SetHotKey()
    Dim ret As Long
    bCancel = False
    ret = RegisterHotKey(Application.hwnd, &HBFFE&, 0, VK_SNAPSHOT)
    ProcessMessages
End Sub

Sub UnsetHotKey()
    bCancel = True
    Call UnregisterHotKey(Application.hwnd, &HBFFE&)
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the purpose? You want to make your users unhappy?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity